# This query on mysql is taking forever to execute

Tags: php, mysql

im making a simple admin module to query the database to show the results. Im using this query via php:

```
SELECT
* 
FROM myTable 
WHERE id in(SELECT 
            id_registro 
            FROM myOtherTable 
            where id_forma='".$id_club."' and fecha_visita Like '%".$hoy."%'
            )
order by id DESC
```

The result shows, however, it takes very long like 2 minutes..Anyone can help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: if you can turn the sub query in to a join it would be faster, also depends on your indexing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your database, it is hard to find a way to make it faster.
Maybe you can try to turn your `WHERE IN` to `INNER JOIN`. To something like this

```
SELECT * FROM myTable INNER JOIN myOtherTable
ON (myTable.id = myOtherTable.id_registro)
WHERE myOtherTable.id_forma = '$id_club'
AND myOtherTable.fecha_visita LIKE '%$hoy%'
ORDER BY myTable.id DESC
```

Noted that you should sanitize your variable before putting it SQL query or using PDO prepare statement.

Comment: hello! thanks for answering, im trying it and i get this error:  [Column 'id' in on clause is ambiguous]

Comment: are you sure you used both table names?

Comment: @ChrisVillegas, `Column 'id' in on clause is ambiguous` means that both `myTable` and `myOtherTable` has same `id` column. So you need to specified which table does `id` from by using `myTable.id`. I have edit my query and you can try again.

Answer (score 1):

Sub Queries takes always time, so its better to ignore them as much as possible.

Try to optimize your query by checking its cardinality,possible keys getting implemented by `DESC or EXPLAIN` , and if necessary use `FORCE INDEX` over possible keys.

and I guess you can modify your query as:

```
SELECT
* 
FROM myTable 
inner join id_registro 
on (id = id_forma )
where
 id_forma='".$id_club."' and fecha_visita Like '%".$hoy."%'
order by id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

LIKE in mysql may take a long time ,with or without index.
Do u have a very large DB?